# Defining field values using an other fields values Esri Arcmap

Tags: python, polygon, esri, arcmap, data-management

I´m using arcMap, Esri. I have a polyline layer with information in text which I need to convert to number values. I want accomplish this using scripting with Python in the Field calculator.

My challenge:
Using field values in one field I want to define values in another field. 
In my case I need to define the width of a road in numbers, depending on the field value in text from another field. 
The road "widthNumber" will depend on the value of another fields value "widthText".

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of ways you can do this. I'm making the assumption both fields are in the same feature class/shapefile and the widthNumber field is an int of some type.

The ideal case is to use a switch case (Java/C#), but those don't exist in python. So we can either use a dictionary to sort of recreate the switch or simply load up on ifs'. I'm a fan of cleaner code so I've included the logic for the dictionary. But you can always move that into a bunch of ifs' as you deem necessary.

All you have to do is use the pre-logic script code area to write a function which accepts the widthText and returns the widthNumber.

```
def calculateValue(text):
switcher ={
    "Ones":1,
    "Fivers":5,
    "Threebs":3,
    "Twotow":2,
    "Four":4,
    "Fivers":5
}
return switcher.get(text,"Invalid")`
```

Then in the bottom section you just call that function and pass in the attribute..
              calculateValue(!widthText!)

[image]

In this example I did not write in any error handling to deal with invalid values, depending on how your values are stored it may be smart to ensure everything is in the same case (Upper/Lower) to ensure consistency.